# How do I cancel a published ReadyToWork in my Cell?

Tags: moryx

I'm implementing a cell that publishes a RTW (Push) and waits for Activities. However, under certain circumstances I want to take back the RTW and replace it with a RTW (Pull). Following is a simplified example of what I want to achieve:

```cs
public class SomeCell: Cell
{
    [EntrySerialize]
    public void SendReadyToWorkPush()
    {
        var rtw = Session.StartSession(ActivityClassification.Production, ReadyToWorkType.Push);
        PublishReadyToWork(rtw);
    }

    [EntrySerialize]
    public void SendReadyToWorkPull(long processId)
    {
        // Take Back any previous RTW Push that was send
        var rtw = Session.StartSession(ActivityClassification.Production, ReadyToWorkType.Pull, processId);
        PublishReadyToWork(rtw);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remember the last published session and publish a NotReadyToWork.

```
    public class SomeCell : Cell
    {
        private ReadyToWork _rtw;

        [EntrySerialize]
        public void SendReadyToWorkPush()
        {
            var notReadyToWork = _rtw.PauseSession();
            PublishNotReadyToWork(notReadyToWork);

            _rtw = Session.StartSession(ActivityClassification.Production, ReadyToWorkType.Push);
            PublishReadyToWork(_rtw);
        }

        [EntrySerialize]
        public void SendReadyToWorkPull(long processId)
        {
            // Take Back any previous RTW Push that was send
            var notReadyToWork = _rtw.PauseSession();
            PublishNotReadyToWork(notReadyToWork);

            _rtw = Session.StartSession(ActivityClassification.Production,  ReadyToWorkType.Pull, processId);
            PublishReadyToWork(_rtw);
        }
    }
```